# CodeDeploy succeeds only once

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to deploy a Discord bot written in Java on an AWS EC2 instance using CodeDeploy.

I installed the CodeDeploy agent and tried deploying and it worked fine. However, when I tried deploying again I got this error:

> The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems.

When I check event logs it's failing on the first step `ApplicationStop`

```
LifecycleEvent - ApplicationStop
Script - stop_bot.sh
[stderr]java: no process found
```

Here's my appspec.yml:

```yaml
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /DuoCord-0.1.jar
    destination: /tmp
hooks:
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: start_bot.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: stop_bot.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

start_bot.sh:

```bash
nohup java -jar /tmp/DuoCord-0.1.jar dev.rifaii.Main /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &
```

stop_bot.sh:

```bash
killall -9 java
```

I tried uninstalling the codedeploy-agent and installing it again and the deployment worked, but again on the second attempt it gave the same error

Comment: Do you know why Java terminates before `stop_bot.sh` runs to terminate it?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary does it?

Comment: 'Script - stop_bot.sh [stderr]java: no process found' - meaning Java has already terminated so `killall` can't find a process to kill, which then makes your script fail. You can make it just do a simple if check to see if it's still running but not sure what you're expecting here without more info on the bot. Did you copy paste the command in `start_bot.sh` from somewhere?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary indeed the problem was in stop_bot.sh, I posted more detailed answer below

Comment: Glad you got it sorted but FYI it's usually good SO etiquette to allow the person who answered your question, to answer the question. All good in this case but just for future questions :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like my stop_bot.sh fails when no Java processes are running and on the first deployment after installing CodeDeploy, it isn't running ApplicationStop and that's why it succeeds.

I replaced my stop_bot.sh script with this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check if any Java processes are running
java_pids=$(pgrep java)

if [ -n "$java_pids" ]; then
  # Stop all Java processes
  for pid in $java_pids; do
    kill -9 "$pid"
    echo "Java process stopped (PID: $pid)"
  done
else
  echo "No Java processes found"
fi
```

and start_bot.sh with this:

```bash
nohup java -jar /tmp/DuoCord-0.1.jar dev.rifaii.Main
```

This fixed the issue